# What is IronPython good for if it cannot load any third party packages?

Tags: python, .net, pandas, numpy, ironpython

I was under the assumption that I can use the .NET script engine, create a script engine, scope and can happily import Python libraries such as I can with any other Python interpreter. However, huge disappointment followed.

Neither NumPy nor pandas nor a host of other analytical packages work in IronPython. I am not talking about ports but about the same packages that work on all the other Python variants.

Am I missing something or do I need to give up on the idea to run a full fledged Python engine within .NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is IronPython good for if it cannot load any third party packages?

[IronPython *can* work with third-party libraries](http://ironpython.net/documentation/dotnet/); they just have to be written in .NET. That means that most well-known Python libraries won't work, but it also opens the door to a whole other ecosystem.

> Neither NumPy nor pandas nor a host of other analytical packages work in IronPython.

Python isn't just for numerical computation, but if that is what you're after I recommend either looking for similar libraries written in .NET or sticking with CPython (or maybe PyPy).